# Calculate the number of trials needed to achieve certain number of successes at a confidence level

Tags: binomial-distribution

If I know the probability of success for an event, the number of time that I want to observe the event at a certain confidence level how do I calculate the number of trials needed?

Comment: I think you need to re-think/rewrite your question. See this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/416194/how-long-does-it-take-to-fill-a-bucket-to-capacity-if-randomly-adding-items-to-b#comment776672_416194

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say your Success probability is $p=0.3,$ your target number of Successes is $k = 10$ and your target probability of fulfillment is 0.95.

Then you seek $n$ sufficiently large that $P(X \ge 10) = 0.95,$
given that $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n, p=0.3).$

For most values of $p,$ you could get a close answer by
obtaining a normal approximation of $P(X \ge 10)$ and solving for $n.$

However, it is simple to search for $n$ using R. First, we
guess that $n = 100$ might we large enough. So we use R
to find that $P(X \ge 10) = 1 - P(X \le 9) = 0.9999996 > 0.95,$ using `pbinom`, which
denotes a binomial CDF in R:

```
1 - pbinom(9, 100, .3) 
[1] 0.9999996
```

Also it is obvious that $n \ge 10.$ So we look at all values
of $n$ between 10 and 100 inclusive, and pick the smallest
$n$ that works. [In R, `n` is a numerical vector of length 91, thus `bpr` is a numerical vector of length 91, and `bpr >= .95` is a logical vector of length 91, containing `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s, You can read the bracket notation `[ ]` as "such that." ]

```
n = 10:100;  k = 10;  p= .3
bpr = 1 - pbinom(k-1, n, p)
min(n[bpr >= .95])
[1] 49
```

Thus $n = 49$ should be barely large enough and $n = 48$ not quite
large enough.  We verify that this is true:

```
1 - pbinom(9, 49, .3)
[1] 0.9520446
1 - pbinom(9, 48, .3)
[1] 0.9430372
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Does this problem/test have a name?